# Launching script to export environment variables from Python

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

**I'm trying to remove all passwords and secrets from applications.**

To do this, I'm using environment variables. I would like to avoid putting this specific stuff into `~/.bashrc` or other built in files. It would be ideal to call a specific script that exports the desired variables.

The reason for this is because the environment variables contain passwords and I'm trying to isolate them outside of all code except the environment scripts that set environment variables.

**To summarize the desired flow:**

1. Launch Python app
2. App spawns process that sets new environment variables
3. App pulls values from previously set environment variables
4. App uses those values in further processing

> contents of testpy.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import subprocess

env_file='/tmp/env_file'
db_pass_var='DBPASS'

#execute bash script that sets the env vars
subprocess.call([".", env_file], shell=True)

#try to get the variable set and print it
print os.getenv(db_pass, 'fail')
```

> contents of /tmp/env_file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export DBUSER="myuser"
export DBPASS="mypass"
```

I've tried various methods like `subprocess.Popen` commands I found on other stackoverflow threads but nothing seems to work.

**Alternatives that I want to avoid:**

- Running the env_file script first, then launching the python code. The goal is to run it all from 1 application.
- Putting the passwords into a config file. The goal is environment variables. Config files I would like to reserve to pointing to what variable to call, rather than setting the env vars themselves. This is because config files are checked into source control. The only thing I want to leave out of source control is the actual `export` environment variables themselves which contain all sensitive environment info.

Comment: Changes to environment variables can't ever be seen by a process's parent, so what you want to do can't work.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to set the environment elsewhere before the main app runs. I need a language-agnostic workflow to handle this sort of thing and it sounds like just setting the user environment profile before the applications launch (rather than during) is the only way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an easier way. Just provide a wrapper script that sets the environment variables and then calls your main script.

It's convenient to use the `envdir` utility for this. If you can't use that for some reason, then set env vars directly using `os.environ` and spawn off your main script as a child process.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think wrapping it is going to be the only way. Problem is that this was just a "proof of concept" method for my team as I'm tasked with developing a method of hiding secrets from code. Team uses node.js, Python, and Java in our apps and was hoping to find a unified way of doing it across everything which leaves `envdir` out of the question.

Comment: `envdir` is a command line app and can be used to launch any of the environments you mentioned. Works everywhere.

Comment: Thank you. I was just reading up on it and it looked like a Python pip package but I see that's just a port. Much appreciated. I'll mark this as the accepted answer in a day or two if nothing else pops up.

Comment: `envdir` is working perfectly. Marking this as the answer

Comment: It is a great tool. See `envshell` and `envconsul` for the same idea in different deployment models.